# How do I get squid peers to talk SSL to each other?

Tags: ssl, squid

How would I set up a pair of squid proxies so that one uses the other as a parent and all traffic between them is encrypted using SSL? I've read the cache_peer documentation, but it's all very fuzzy to me which certs I need to create (and how), which server uses which cert, and so on. Is there a straightforward HOW-TO for this somewhere?

Just to be clear, I don't want to know how to setup squid to proxy https requests, or as a reverse proxy for a web server that uses https.

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the squid version, and the cache peer/parenting has changed a bit recently.

Under squid 2.7 the client side should look a little like:

```
cache_peer parent.fqdn parent SSL-PORT 0 ssl
always_direct deny all
never_direct allow all
```

You may want client certs if you want to authenticate both sides, however that requires building a CA and even a simple one is *painful*.

The server end there's more options.

Comment: Building & managing a CA is dead simple with tinyca2:
http://tinyca.sm-zone.net/

Comment: @Eddy I disagree, I've built several CA's, and it's not the actual CA maintenance work that's the issue, it's everything else around it.